# Jquery convert object to string and slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Via ajax-based script i get object:

for example:

```
item.TYP_PCON_START
```

which value is, for example 201212...
When i try to slice him, i get oject error...

How could i slice this object so, that for example i get 2012, or better set two last numbers on furst place and add dot, like:

```
12.2012
```

How could i do this? (i append this text as value of select list)

Comment: What does `typeof item.TYP_PCON_START` say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice the string property, not the object itself:

```
item.TYP_PCON_START.slice(-2) + '.' + item.TYP_PCON_START.slice(0, 4);
> '12.2012'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Hdme/

edit: In the case that your property is a number, you must convert it to a string before attempting to slice it:

```
var propertyAsString = item.TYP_PCON_START.toString();
propertyAsString.slice(-2) + '.' + propertyAsString.slice(0, 4);
> '12.2012'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Hdme/1/

Comment: i get Object 200001 has no method 'slice'

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris are you sure `item.TYP_PCON_START` is a string? If it is a number then you need to call `.toString()` before `.slice()`

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris i'm fairly certain that I am not blind, and jQuery has nothing to do with this problem. The `slice()` method exists on `String` objects only, so if you have a number then you need to convert it to a string by using `toString()` before calling `slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = item.TYP_PCON_START,
        a = a+"",
        a = a.split("");
    a.splice(2,0,".");
    a = a.join("");
    a = parseFloat(a);
    console.log(a);
```